# sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.glassfish.hk2#hk2-utils;2.22.2: not found

Tags: scala, apache-spark, playframework, apache-kafka, sbt

I am new to Play framework.

I tried to add libraries of Spark and Kafka in build.sbt but I get 
this error:

```
  of org.glassfish.hk2. and org.glassfish.hk2#hk2-locator;2.22.2: not 
 found and javax.validation#validation- 
  api;${javax.validation.version}: not found
```

Whenever I run play run it downloads jar files , later gives 
      glassfish errors. 
The errors I got is

[image: sbt error]

```
  Here are the codes:

    name := "smack"
   version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

  libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
 anorm,
  cache
   )     

  play.Project.playScalaSettings

  libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
   "com.datastax.cassandra"  % "cassandra-driver-core" % "2.0.2",
   jdbc,
    anorm,
     cache)

   // logging
   libraryDependencies += "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-log4j12" % "1.7.25"

   // JSON
   libraryDependencies += "com.fasterxml.jackson.module" %% "jackson- 
   module-scala" % "2.8.8"

  // Kafka
  libraryDependencies += "org.apache.kafka" % "kafka-streams" % 
  "0.10.2.0"

   libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % 
   "2.3.0"
  libraryDependencies += "org.apache.kafka" % "kafka-clients" % 
  "2.0.0"
```

How can I solve this dependency problems?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited the title of your question to fix image display and correct wordings in the sentences.

Answer (score 0):

I solved error.
I changed my play version in plugins.sbt

// The Typesafe repository 
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

// Use the Play sbt plugin for Play projects

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.2.6")

and also added

// Typesafe snapshots
resolvers += "Typesafe Snapshots" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/snapshots/"

it solved my error .

for reference :

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.6/NewApplication